# Python: How to Handle the Exception to Class variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have no idea to implement to handle the class variable exception. I am trying to create python module which has dependency with `mongodb`.

```
class HrmLookUps(DBMixin):
    db_handle = DBMixin.get_db_handle(DBMixin, MONGO_STORE_DICT.get("DB_NAME"),
                                      MONGO_STORE_DICT.get("DB_HOST"),
                                      MONGO_STORE_DICT.get("DB_PORT"),
                                      MONGO_STORE_DICT.get("USERNAME"),
                                      MONGO_STORE_DICT.get("PASSWORD"))

    @classmethod
    def get_gender(cls):
        collection_name = COLLECTION_NAME_DICT.get("COLLECTION_GENDER")
        # collection_name = "departments"
        gender_record = cls.get_from_db(cls, cls.db_handle, collection_name)
        if gender_record[collection_name]:
            return gender_record
        else:
            raise KeyError("Collection Name Invalid!")
```

I have multiple get method like above get_gender(). I am handling each method raised `Keyerror` if its data empty.
My question is,

1. Is this proper way to handle exception of methods?
2. If my class variable has some issues ex.database credential wrong how can I handle that?

Comment: It actually looks like your `else` clause is doing nothing.  if `collection_name` isn't a key in `gender_record`  then your if statement is going to throw the keyerror for you and the `else` statement will just be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your else clause isn't really doing anything.  Your if statement would already throw an error if `collection_name` wasn't a key in `gender_record`.  So unless you want to raise `KeyError` in the else clause when `collection_name` is in `gender_record` but its value happens to be `0` or `False` or `None`.

I think what you are trying to do is something closer to these examples:

```py
    @classmethod
    def get_gender(cls):
        collection_name = COLLECTION_NAME_DICT.get("COLLECTION_GENDER")
        # collection_name = "departments"
        gender_record = cls.get_from_db(cls, cls.db_handle, collection_name)
        if collection_name in gender_record:
            return gender_record
        else:
            raise KeyError("Collection Name Invalid!")
```

or this maybe

```py
    @classmethod
    def get_gender(cls):
        collection_name = COLLECTION_NAME_DICT.get("COLLECTION_GENDER")
        # collection_name = "departments"
        gender_record = cls.get_from_db(cls, cls.db_handle, collection_name)
        try:
            gender_record[collection_name]
            return gender_record
        else KeyError as err:
            raise KeyError("Collection Name Invalid!") from err
```

Handling exceptions is pretty much the same in any situation. so for the credentials it would be something like this:

```py
try:
    db_handle = DBMixin.get_db_handle(DBMixin, MONGO_STORE_DICT.get("DB_NAME"),
                                      MONGO_STORE_DICT.get("DB_HOST"),
                                      MONGO_STORE_DICT.get("DB_PORT"),
                                      MONGO_STORE_DICT.get("USERNAME"),
                                      MONGO_STORE_DICT.get("PASSWORD"))
except <SomeCredentialErrorHere>:
   # whatever you put here is what gets executed if the error is raised.
```